# Find the relation between ".automaticDestinations-ms" and it's file?

Tags: windows, windows-7

Does anyone know (Because on microsoft forums nobody answered me), how can I find what app has which automaticDestinations-ms file in  **%appdata%\microsoft\windows\recent\automaticdestinations** ?

That's the folder where Windows 7 stores its jump lists, and I want to know how to automatically/programmatic find the relation between each file and an application.

At least, even manual I didn't found any pattern, just to look after file extensions in the files, because some programs open files with the same extension (like images), so this method it's not OK for all programs.

Do you have any other idea? Maybe knowing the format of those files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to find out is to sort the files by date modified, then interact with your machine, eg open a file with Powerpoint, look and see what file moved to the top. That is probably the file for Powerpoint, which you can confirm by opening it and looking in it.

Then you could build a table of magic guids, and search for those in the registry to see if there is an obvious key connecting the guid to an application id.

Comment: Hi!. I've already done that, and got a list of guids for some applications. My wonder is, if that those guids are non-transient, that is, they keep the same numbers/letters on each machine and version. But I never got the idea to search through the registry

Comment: It seems there is nothing in the registry connecting/having any of the guids :(.

Comment: In tracking down an issue with the jumplist for Windows Explorer I can tell you the guid for Windows Explorer is consistent across machines. It's the same for everyone. I therefore think the same is true for other apps.

Answer (score 4):

the GUIDs appear to persist.

I was trying to edit my control panel jumplist - I found where the "Realtek HD audio manager" control-panel-applet-title-string is (using resource hacker on "C:\Windows\System32\RTSnMg64.cpl"), and restored  it's original title ("Dell Audio" - 'cause I'm OCD:) but the original pinned Realtek entry is stuck.

A quick filesearch for **pinned** took me to

C:\Users\Jonny\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned

but I really needed to be @ C:\Users\Jonny\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations

If you use something like **[Nirsoft's Jumplist View](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/jump_lists_view.html)** you can see the entries etc. Sort by "application ID" column to see jumplists by application. You can even change the monitored folder (advanced options).

I'm going to have to delete and recreate my control panel jumplist (7e4dca80246863e3.automaticDestinations-ms).

[image]
TIP: If you're not sure which is which, try pinning a new jumplist-entry to an application. This will appear at the top (if sorted by "record time")

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of 620 applications here with the corresponding App ID byEricZimmerman
https://github.com/EricZimmerman/JumpList/blob/master/JumpList/Resources/AppIDs.txt

eg 0a1d19afe5a80f80|FileZilla 2.2.32

last update 12 days ago